# Vue.js Webpack module is not found / imported

Tags: webpack, vue.js

I wrote an AuthService to use with the vue router, but I can not import the AuthService into my router file, I get the following error:

```
_auth_AuthService__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__ is not a constructor
```

I am importing like this: `import AuthService from '../auth/AuthService'`

And exporting like this: `export default class AuthService {...}`

In the App.Vue file I have no problem using the AuthService, where import the service like this:

```
import AuthService from './auth/AuthService'
const auth = new AuthService()
const { login, logout, authenticated, authNotifier } = auth
```

Maybe it is some kind of setup problem ?

Comment: Are you using Auth0?

Comment: Yes I am usin Auth0

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with that. I issue is located in the AuthService. I have resolved this issue by initialising auth inside the constructor. e.g.,

```
class AuthService {

  constructor() {
    this.login = this.login.bind(this)
    this.setSession = this.setSession.bind(this)
    this.logout = this.logout.bind(this)
    this.isAuthenticated = this.isAuthenticated.bind(this)
    this.authenticated = this.isAuthenticated()
    this.authNotifier = new EventEmitter()
    this.auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth({
      domain: AUTH_CONFIG.domain,
      clientID: AUTH_CONFIG.clientId,
      redirectUri: AUTH_CONFIG.callbackUrl,
      audience: `https://${AUTH_CONFIG.domain}/userinfo`,
      responseType: 'token id_token',
      scope: 'openid'
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Still getting the same error message though.